# Input data to MySQL fails

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to send some information to mysql database but it keeps returning input data fail. Here is my code

```
<?php

    $Firstname='';
    $Lastname='';
    $Email='';
    $Birthcountry='';
    $Phone='';
    $Occupation='';



    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "canadavisa";
    $tblname = "canadav";

    // Create connection
    mysql_connect("$servername","$username","$password");
    mysql_select_db("$dbname");


    //the example of inserting data with variable from HTML form

    //input.php
    //mysql_connect("localhost","username","");//database connection

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //mysql_select_db("canadavisa"); 
    $Firstname = $_POST['Firstname'];
    $Lastname = $_POST['Lastname'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Birthcountry = $_POST['Birthcountry'];
    $Phon e= $_POST['Phone'];
    $Occupation = $_POST['Occupation'];
    }
    //inserting data into mysql database



    $order="INSERT INTO canadav(Firstname,Lastname,Email,Birthcountry,Phone,Occupation)VALUES('$Firstname','$Lastname','$Email','$Birthcountry','$Phone','$Occupation')";


    //declare in the order variable

    $result=mysql_query($order);  //order executes

    if($result){

        echo("<br>Input data is successful");
        echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
    } else{

        echo("<br>Input data is fail");

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Your code seems to check out, if `mysql_` is still available for you to use. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. You may need to use `mysqli_` or PDO, and check all your form's elements. POST/PHP/form variables are case-sensitive. Your code also depends on the conditional statement you've given it, so make sure the button is named.

Comment: Please do not use the `root` user to connect to MySQL from PHP. Ever. Not even during development.

Comment: Output the query string and run it through mysql to see the error as well.

Comment: I just spotted it now `$Phon e= $_POST['Phone'];` *duh.* Anyway, checking for errors would have spotted that syntax error.

Comment: @DaveRandom from the code this appears to be someone learning PHP. I agree with your comment, but for a beginner that might not be such as easy thing to do at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error here:

```
$Phon e= $_POST['Phone'];
```

There are an extra space, remove that.

```
$Phone= $_POST['Phone'];
```

**NOTE**

- Do not use mysql functions, they are deprecated use mysqli or PDO instead.
- Escape your variables to avoid sql injections, or use prepared statements.